# Eclipse doesn't detect my phone?

Tags: android

I installed Google Services v2 in Eclipse and I created a simple main activity in the app. I followed all instructions in http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html and there weren't errors.

But when I run the app, I visualized the following in the console:

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing es.mapas.Principal activity launch
Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
Starting activity es.mapas.Principal on device LGOTMS1a1ca6c
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=es.mapas/.Principal }
```

So it means that Eclipse recognized my LG's phone. But when I clicked in Android Virtual Manager icon I only saw the virtual device I build but anything about my phone. Did Eclipse detect my phone?

After running the app I of my phone I didn't see the maps.

Thanks.